# How to get value before it changes? In knockout.js

Tags: json, mapping, knockout.js

I'm using mapping utils to load some mega JSON data. I know how to detect changes with an 'update' callback.

But how do I compare the old value with new value? In the 'update' callback I get access only to new value.

Of course - when I put update to JSON - I use mapping utils again.

I'd like to know whether the value increases or decreases. How to do this?

Comment: Maybe you could use dependent observables? http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/dependentObservables.html

Comment: Take a look at http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html.  It implements a way of keeping an "original" copy of your data while editing.

Comment: nice photo_tom, that looks like the right way to go about it

Comment: This is great for observables. But when I get big JSON, and insert him into template by var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data); and update this by var ko.mapping.fromJS(dataNEW,viewModel); - I don't know, How to implement this solution. I need to think about it

Comment: I think about my question, And have some solution.
1. Init with data_1   mapping.fromJSON(data_1, viewModel)
2. Get JSON data_2
3. Compare data_1 & data_2. If value in deep-deep branches has grows - add params like "changes":"up" or "changes":"down" in data_2 JSON.
4. mapping.fromJSON (data_2, viewModel)
5. In template I have handler for "changes=up" and for "changes=down" and for no changes.
6. Tomorrow - I will try to make this ;-)

Answer (score 1):

An update callback for the ko.mapping plugin takes one options argument, which is an object containing

- data
- parent
- target

The parent object still holds the old value.

```
var mapping = {
  'prop': 
     update: function(options) {
       var oldval = options.parent.prop;
       var newval = options.data;
       // do something that uses oldval and newval here
       return newval;
   }
}
```